# Upper and Lower bound for Riemann Sums

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum

Why is the set defined as *L* = {L(P) : P is a partition of [a,b]} bounded above 
where L(P) is the lower sum of f relative to P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because any lower sum is bounded above by any upper sum. If $P$ and $P'$ are two partitions of $[a,b]$, then
$$
L(P)\le U(P').
$$